# How to calculate Topocentric Crescent Width and Moon Radius/Semi-Diameter?

Tags: the-moon

I have the Topocentric Moon Altitude, T. Moon Azimuth, T. Sun Altitude, T. Sun Azimuth, T. Elongation, T. Phase Angle.

How do I calculate the Topocentric Crescent Width and the Topocentric Moon Radius/Semi-Diameter?

Is there any other piece of information I need to do this?

Comment: You can say radius instead of semi-diameter

Comment: You need to know the distance to the Moon to calculate the semi-diameter.

Comment: Is that the topocentric distance? I have that also. What's the formula?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the moon to earth distance in km and also the topocentric elongation in radians.

**topo_moon_radius** = asin(1737.1 / moon_to_earth_distance_in_km) * (180 / π)

1737.1 is the moon radius in km.

**topo_cresent_width_in_degrees** = topo_moon_radius * (1 - (cos(topo_elongation_in_radians)))