# How to calculate the Topocentric Elongation of the Moon?

Tags: the-moon

I was trying to calculate the Topocentric Crescent Width and I found this answer, [How to calculate Topocentric Crescent Width and Moon Radius/Semi-Diameter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54123/how-to-calculate-topocentric-crescent-width-and-moon-radius-semi-diameter)

However, I am missing the Topocentric Elongation, I am using the Java Suncalc Library from https://shredzone.org/ so it has many methods for sun moon calculations,

Assuming the formula in the previous post is correct, how to calculate the Topocentric Elongation?

thank you,